# Resposta antiga aceite mas que afinal (presumidamente) nao resolve o problema do perguntador

Tags: debate, respostas, resposta-aceita, respostas-erradas

Ás vezes acontece eu encontrar perguntas antigas com respostas aceites. Mas aparentemente essas respostas efetivamente nao respondem ao problema colocado pelo perguntador.

E tenham calma, eu estou bem ciente que aquilo que acabei de escrever já levanta milhares de alarmes. Afinal de contas se a respota foi aceite é porque ela ajudou o perguntador (supostamente?)

> Clique para aceitar esta resposta pois ela resolveu o seu problema ou foi a mais útil para encontrar a solução (clique novamente para desfazer)

Como estas sao respsotas antigas entao se calhar elas foram aceites simplesmente pelo fato que o perguntador consegiu resolver o problema com a "pista" que lhe foi dada e pela falta de outras respostas que responderiam de fato ao problema.

O caso mais recente que encontrei [foi este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73766/c-mvc5-inserir-campos-com-4-d%C3%ADgitos-decimais?rq=1). O perguntador diz que os dados nao sao guardados na base de dados com as casas decimais corretas. Contudo diz que o valor é atribuido corretamente ao modelo.

> O fato é que quando eu debugo o código, até antes do momento do
>   'context.SaveChanges()', ele está com as casas decimais corretas, ex.:
>   0,8999. Porém, quando eu faço o SaveChanges ele acaba gravando no
>   banco de dados da seguinte forma '0,8900'.

A resposta vem em torno de código que é responsável por atribuir valores ao modelo (ou seja a parte que está a funcionar sem problemas).

O que eu posso fazer nestes cenários?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *primeira conduta* seria contestar o respondedor. Simplesmente porque é mais fácil. A *segunda conduta* seria oferecer uma outra resposta, atacando justamente o que você acha que deu problema.

> Uma *terceira conduta* seria negativar a resposta, se você achar que ela é indigna de estar ali. Eu só costumo negativar respostas que eu ache peçonhentas, venenosas e perigosas (incluindo as totalmente erradas aqui na categoria de venenosas).
>
> Claro, negativar vem junto de toda uma carga semântica e social desse tipo de voto que deve ser levada em consideração ao tomar essa ação.

Por exemplo, nessa questão: [Como utilizar o comando REPITA nesse algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209601/64969)

Eu postei [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209602/64969), só com o trecho significante. Não deixei explícito, mas eu escrevi a resposta naquele molde justamente para que o AP tivesse trabalho e aprendesse ao tentar adaptar seu próprio código para o contexto. Assim ele teria de pensar um pouco e eu aumentaria as chances de ele aprender alguma coisa.

Insatisfeito com minha resposta, o @Yoda postou a [resposta digna na interpretação dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/247883/64969), já mastigada. Eu acho que o AP no momento trocou de resposta aceita (foi estranho ver um -15 nas atualizações, mas já superei isso). Enfim, foi uma discordância da abordagem da resposta, ele atuou no que eu chamei de "segunda conduta". Não lembro se a gente conversou no chat sobre essa pergunta em específica (o que seria a "primeira conduta").

Sobre esse usuário em específico, o @Cigano já colocou até mesmo eu seu perfil que não tem mais interesse em responder coisas aqui o SOpt. Dificilmente ele viria aqui prestar satisfações sobre uma resposta. Então eu creio que oferecer a sua versão seria o adequado a se fazer.

---

Outra coisa seria a questão de etiqueta. Aqui tem uma etiqueta que eu sempre interpretei como uma coisa bem aberta:

> Questão com resposta aceita pode receber novas respostas sem detrimento da anterior e sem precisar prestar satisfações a priori.

Claro, se você oferece uma nova resposta, então não esperamos encontrar mais do mesmo (mesmo que a resposta anterior não seja aceita, se espera isso). Implicitamente você tem algo a ser dito que não foi dito e que não caberia como comentário. Isso pode ser conteúdo ou mesmo uma abordagem distinta.

Eu mesmo [fiz isso semana passada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277763/64969), respondi com outra abordagem [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277758/64969). E, conforme descrevi logo no começo da minha resposta, continuo achando que [a resposta do @jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277762/64969) está mais adequada a nível técnico.

Talvez o @Victor Stafusa tenha feito isso na [resposta sobre o problema da Parada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276746/64969), [achou que a outra resposta estava com a abordagem inadequada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276648/o-que-%C3%A9-um-problema-de-parada-de-turing/276746#comment565541_276746) para a questão:

> @JeffersonQuesado Tentei dar uma resposta menos teórica e muito mais for dummies que a sua.

e o [AP corroborou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276648/o-que-%C3%A9-um-problema-de-parada-de-turing/276658#comment565834_276658) com a opinião do Victor:

> Jefferson, sua resposta está excelente. Mas ainda assim meio confusa para mim e para algumas pessoas. Imagina, por exemplo, como eu explicaria sua explicação para usa sala de aula na sexta série? Para uma pessoa de 13 anos?

Enfim, conclusão?

Se você tem algo a acrescentar, acrescente. Às vezes vão ser apenas comentários de questionamentos, às vezes são outras respostas.

Comment: Vou fazer a minha resposta entao. Acha que o fato da pergunta ser antiga muda alguma coisa?

Comment: @BrunoCosta a idade da pergunta não deveria ser levada em conta para você contribuir para o site (exceto se você estiver atrás da medalha Necromante XD )