# Resposta aceita não contempla totalmente a pergunta

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Fiquei com dúvida referente a [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297554/restringindo-aspas-simples-e-duplas-do-text-%C3%A1rea-mesmo-dando-crlt-v) pergunta, a resposta aceita não contempla totalmente a pergunta (considerando a informação do título da mesma).

O que deve ser feito neste caso?

- Edita-se a pergunta removendo parte do título deixando-a coerente.
- Deixar comentário para que o AR ajuste sua resposta.

Qual seria a melhor abordagem?

Comment: O que falta na resposta aceita?

Comment: Se contempla ou não a pergunta, ainda é o AP que decide. Se você acha que a resposta é insuficiente, você pode tanto comentar para que o autor da mesma complete ou pode criar outra resposta que atenda aquilo que não foi contemplado na resposta aceita.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a parte do ctrl+v

Comment: A sugestão minha é você elaborar uma resposta melhor e comentar para o autor dando enfase máxima. :)

Comment: Henrique as perguntas não precisam de uma única resposta. Eu já vi altor trocar a resposta aceita pois depois apareceu uma mais adequada etc. Além disso tem pergunta com mais de 20 respostas por ai. Não ache que só pq já tem uma resposta vc não deveria responder com o seu ponto de vista. E se vc achar necessário comente na resposta aceita que faltou alguma coisa ou que tem algum erro, isso é normal de fazer e de receber tb, criticas e dicas são normais, comentário é pra isso.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Resposta antiga aceite mas que afinal (presumidamente) nao resolve o problema do perguntador](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6838/resposta-antiga-aceite-mas-que-afinal-presumidamente-nao-resolve-o-problema-do)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não é porque uma pergunta tem uma resposta aceita que significa que ela esta fechada para novas respostas, se você tem solução melhor, se acredita que as demais respostas não abordam o problema, então pode formular uma resposta detalhada e comentar para o AP (só para dar o reforço).

Se não sabe como resolver, ou se deseja uma resposta melhor pode lançar uma recompensa na pergunta e descrever isto nela.

> PS: no momento criei uma resposta que acredito que resolva de forma bem mais simples o problema da pergunta linkada:
>
> - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297651/3635